# What should be the order of applied filters chips?

Tags: filter, material-design

I'm following material guidelines and I need to apply filters to a table. The table header has the filter icon on the right side

[image: Unexpanded filter Title]

After the filter is applied, should the position of the "applied filter chip" be on the right or on the left?

[image: Option 1]
[image: Option 2]

Answer (score 1):

##### Keeping the filter on the right provides a stable visual location to invoke the action.

There may not be a hard rule to this, but at a quick glance the user will see the icon in the same place, regardless of the viewport width and number of filters.

The other advantage is if you have a design system that shows all the filters, with 2-3 filter chips, you can remove them while the icon remains in place, as opposed to shifting to the right each time a filter is removed.

**Thoughts about the filter chip**

I'm not sure of your use case, but can you put the actual parameter being filtered, instead of '1 filter applied'?

This way the user knows what the filter consists of so they can assess the results.

[image]

Here's how the filters could stack while keeping the action icon in the same place:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @mike-m for a good explaination and improving my filter chips.